# Parquet VS Database

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I am trying to understand which of the below two would be better option especially in case of Spark environment :

1. Loading the parquet file directly into a dataframe and access the data (1TB of data table)
2. Using any database to store and access the data.

I am working on data pipeline design and trying to understand which of the above two options will result in more optimized solution.

Comment: Do you have 1TB of memory to store your data using Spark?

Comment: 1TB is the total size of data I am processing.

Comment: And Spark prefers all that be in available in memory. Is that data compressed, or raw? Parquet or plain text? What database are you even comparing against? For what use case are you optimizing?

Comment: Data is in Parquet format.
For Database I am considering Amazon Aurora/Hive (HDFS base)

Comment: And how do you plan on loading this 1 TB worth of data? Is it currently in HDFS? Worth pointing out - Hive isn't a database, really. It's a SQL  framework abstraction over HDFS files

Comment: For what it's worth, in my experience, reading the raw data is always faster than going through some other  SQL query. Whether that's by Hive or JDBC. But that assumes that the data is on some distributed filesystem where data locality matters (ie HDFS rather s3)

Comment: Data (parquet file) is located in Amazon S3

Comment: _italic_ For what it's worth, in my experience, reading the raw data is always faster than going through some other SQL query. Whether that's by Hive or JDBC. But that assumes that the data is on some distributed filesystem where data locality matters (ie HDFS rather s3)   <br/>
Won't abstraction layer of database going to help in scanning the data faster compared to reading raw data. That's what the whole purpose of dataframe like hive (I agree that hive is like frame on top of data rather then actual actual database)

Comment: You would think so - however Spark is a distributed execution framework and every executor is going to be running the same query. Let's say you stick a `LIMIT` on a query, force the number of executors to 10, but you notice that Spark starts processing  10x more data than necessary... I've seen it happen - now, I could have been doing it wrong, but my point is that if you're deciding to use Hive, I don't see the point. Spark can read s3 data without it. If you strictly only care about SQL, then use something else

Answer (score 1):

Loading the parquet file directly into a dataframe and access the data is more scalable comparing to reading RDBMS like Oracle through JDBC connector. I handle the data more the 10TB but I prefer ORC format for better performance. I suggest you have to directly read data from files the reason for that is data locality - if your run your Spark executors on the same hosts, where HDFS data nodes located and can effectively read data into memory without network overhead. See https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-data-locality.html and How does Apache Spark know about HDFS data nodes? for more details.

Comment: @cricket_007, @Sahil; : Thanks for the comments. Let me do some small POC to validate the results.